# JS Script for validating dochub pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, formvalidation-plugin

Is it possible to add javascript validations to pdf in dochub. I am not sure how can I integrate js script with dochub. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Verified with dochub support, currently it's not possible to add JS